# How to bold match items in two list boxes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to bold matched items between two list boxes in jquery. I have tried with the following code but it is giving me an error.

```
var $itemInBox1 = $("#box1View").find("option"),
        $itemInBox2 = $("#box2View").find("option");

        $itemInBox1.each(function () {
            var itemInBox1 = this.val();
            $itemInBox2.each(function() {
                var itemInBox2 = this.val();

                if (itemInBox1 == itemInBox2)
                {
                    $itemInBox1.css("font-weight","bold");
                }
            });
        });
```

sample jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5fD5/)

Comment: I think if you have implemented Felix answer and it still fails we need to see a quick fiddle.

Comment: i have added jsfiddle

Comment: I am looking at this I notice chrome will not bold a list item at all. IE will. Chrome will respect font-color. When I run your fiddle the match code never fires. Is this where the real issue is?

Comment: issue is in this line `var itemInBox2 = this.text();`. it gives me an error `TypeError: string is not a function`

Comment: I think that $(this).text() is the correction. See my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what I have working: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/s5fD5/3/)

I did shorten the height so I could see both. Chrome ignores bold. However you can see the working code here with the commented alerts.

```
$("#box1View option").each(function (i) {
    //alert( $(this).text() + " : " + $(this).val() );

    var opt = $(this).text();
    $('#box2View option:contains('+ opt +')').css("font-weight", "bold");  
    $('#box2View option:contains('+ opt +')').css("color", "red");
});
```

HTH

Comment: You could check for browsers or something but I thought this was the best answer without going to far in the weeds.

Comment: thank you it help me out. let me ask you one more question. I can see the color change to red but not bold. what I am missing here?

Comment: Chrome ignores bold for option text. :( IE will show bold options. I added color to make it work in both browsers.

Comment: Looking at this I realized that the "if" is not needed. http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/s5fD5/3/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use correct syntax for **[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)**:

```
$itemInBox1.css("font-weight","bold");
```

or:

```
$itemInBox1.css({"font-weight":"bold"});
```

instead of:

```
$itemInBox1.css("font-weight:bold");
```

Comment: thanks for the correction. but that is not the problem I am facing.

Comment: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: Did you include jQuery or do you use any plugin that is incorrectly included? Can you set up a demo?

Comment: I have use jquery dualListBox plugin. I am trying to bold the matching items from the two list boxes.